# access a latest changed file from a folder using spark(spark specific APIs)

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, azure-blob-storage

I try to access the latest added file in the sample location using spark's `sc.textfile('/home/sathya/location/*.txt')`
But, I need to take the latest added file instead of getting all the files under the directory.

Thanks,
Sathiyarajan M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the latest modified file from the directory and pass it to `sc.textFile()` to read in spark.

Here is how you can get latest modified file

```
val directory = new File("/home/sathya/location/")
val allFiles = directory.listFiles
  .filter(_.isFile)
  .sortBy(-_.lastModified())
  .toList

val latestFile = allFiles(0)
```

Here the `latestFile` is the latest modified file now you can read the latest file into spark as

```
sc.textFile(latestFile)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept as an answer and close the topic. which will also be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

There are no out-of-box solution for your problem, first you find out the latest file then load it.

**Java Example:**

```
/**
 * Function to get latest file in directory
 */
public static String latestFileInDir(String dir) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //Replace hadoop home
    String command = "<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hadoop fs -ls -R " + dir + " | awk -F\" \" '{print $6\" \"$7\" \"$8}' | sort -nr | head -1";

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", command);
    String op = null;
    Process process = pb.start();
    int errCode = process.waitFor();
    if (errCode == 0) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        op = br.readLine();
    }

    return op;
}
```

**Get latest directory and load**

```
  rdd= sc.textfile(latestFileInDir("/home/sathya/location/"));
```